# Java 8 predicate collection with Or Opertion/And Operation and closure

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have below snippet

```
        String s1=null;
        Double d1=null;
        Integer i1=null;
        Predicate<String> p1 = (e->e.equals("correct string"));
        Predicate<Integer> p2 = (i->i%2 == 0);
        Predicate<Double> p3 = (d->d.isNaN());
        List<Predicate<?>> l = List.of(p1,p2,p3);
```

Objective: I want to pass `s1` to `p1`, `d1` to `p2` and `i1` to p3 and may want a final boolean by doing `and` operation or `or` operation of all predicates.
I want to add them to the collection and want each predicate to operate on the respective argument. How do I do that?
Also is there a better way to have a collection than have `?`

Comment: Can you encapsulate the data in a class/record and create multiple `Predicate<Foo>` objects? Then it's easy to use `Predicate::or` and `Predicate::and`. Or you could just create one `Predicate` from the start in that case.

Comment: Trying to collect these in a `List` is already going to be a mess.  If you can't combine the three values into a class/record, it's going to be extremely ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Make classes for this.  This sort of thing is what classes are for.

```
public record Data(String s,
                   double d,
                   int i) {
    // Deliberately empty
}

public record DataChecker(Predicate<? super String> stringTest,
                          DoublePrediate doubleTest,
                          IntPredicate intTest)
implements Predicate<Data> {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Data data) {
        return stringTest().test(data.s())
            && doubleTest().test(data.d())
            && intTest().test(data.i());
    }

    public boolean anyValueMatches(Data data) {
        return stringTest().test(data.s())
            || doubleTest().test(data.d())
            || intTest().test(data.i());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Data data = new Data("example", 1.5, 4);

DataChecker checker = new DataChecker(
    e -> e.equals("correct string"),
    i -> i % 2 == 0,
    Double::isNaN);

System.out.println(checker.test(data));
System.out.println(checker.anyValueMatches(data));
```

Trying to use a List of different Predicates will be quite awkward and will require a lot of unsafe casting.